# Wrap Bash/Unix line oriented pipe in a json structure

Tags: json, bash, pipe, jq

How can I convert this

```
http://www.google.co.uk
http://www.reddit.com
http://www.ebay.com
```

to this using `jq` if possible:

```
{ "listing": "http://www.google.co.uk" }
{ "listing": "http://www.reddit.com" }
{ "listing": "http://www.ebay.com" }
```

What I tried:

```
$ echo "    http://www.google.co.uk
>     http://www.reddit.com
>     http://www.ebay.com"  |  jq --slurp --raw-input 'split("\n")[:-1] | map({ listing: .})'
[
  {
    "listing": "    http://www.google.co.uk"
  },
  {
    "listing": "    http://www.reddit.com"
  },
  {
    "listing": "    http://www.ebay.com"
  }
]
```

Braces and stuff cannot be in a line of its own, because I'm doing "line oriented processing" where each line represents a "row" of data.

Answer (score 2):

Create objects for each input line:

```
echo -e "l1\nl2\nl3" | jq -c -R '{"listing": .}'
```

Output:

```
{"listing":"l1"}
{"listing":"l2"}
{"listing":"l3"}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
jq -cR '{listing: .}'
```

This assumes there are no superfluous spaces at the beginning of the input lines. If leading and trailing spaces are to be removed, you could use this composite filter:

```
sub("^ +";"") | sub(" +$";"")
```

Comment: this outputs multiple newlines per each input line

Comment: So you evidently want the -c option.